# Get search box id present on website using javascript and C#

Tags: javascript, c#

I am new to Javascript and C# and wanted to know how to get search box id of the search box present on website. 
Kindly refer the approach i followed

```
            var url = "example.com";

            System.Net.WebRequest req =  (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

            if (res.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                <script type="text/javascript">

                 function searchAlive() {

                 var link_s = document.getElementById('search').value;
                  }

                 </script>
            }
```

Comment: Show some code. What have you tried? Do you want to get the ID in the client side, server side?

Comment: you could use the developer tools in any browser

Comment: add your search box code in question.

Comment: provide some code and show what error u getting.

Comment: Please provide your approach logic(code html + JS) so that any one can help you. Without knowing your exact problem we cant help you.

Comment: js script will not work in c# code

Comment: i have to check if site is up or not and if site is up have to check the search box id. Anyway i can use JS with C#?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the search box id by using Javascript/Jquery using some properties(css,text etc..) of the text box. include html so that we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

If you want use JavaScript:

```
var _Searched = document.getElementById("SearchTextBoxID").val();
```

if you are using C#:

```
string _Searched = SearchTextBoxID.text;
```

you have to show your codes and your approach. what environment you are coding in and what language you are using ?

If you mean you don't know the "SearchBoxInput" ID and you want to get it, you can use other element such as the class name or tag name to get the element value. But as a programmer, you have to know and work with 'ID' when using backend codes like c# and javascript.
if you want to get the id:

```
var inputs = document.getElementByTagName("input");
for(i=0;i<=inputs.lenght;i++){
if(inputs[i].class == "searchClass"){ var id = input[i].id }
}
```

Comment: any keyword that can give me id of the search box in C# or JS? i have to further use that id in code if the text we enter through code provides any result or not

Comment: I have updated the code for you to get the ID of the search text box, you have to know a specific attribute of the input to get the other attributes.